# Add a panel to edit post

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, editor

I would like create a plug in that adds a panel of options to edit post page like the one added by All in One Seo but i cant find any good tutorial of any information about what is the correct action of filter tu use.

Could you point me in the right direction? snippet?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a **[meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)**. There's a decent example on the Codex page, or try looking up tutorials. Here's a very good one:

http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/

Answer (score 0):

yup- you are talking metaboxes.  i always use:

[www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/)

b/c it is crazy powerful and has some very, very neat functionality... but depending on what you need it might also be overkill.